# Как сделать кроссдоменные запросы

Tags: javascript

Выходит ошибка что нельзя отправлять запросы без этих параметров.

```
var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlRequest.open('POST',  $('#SupUrl').val() + "ADMIN_BH_APP/SupWsExtService", false);

xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    alert(xmlRequest.responseXML)
}
```

хотя ответ от сервера приходит и нормальный приходит,

```
SUP.js:32 XMLHttpRequest cannot load     http://10.44.175.4:3680/ADMIN_BH_APP/SupWsExtService. No 'Access-Control-Allow-   Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.supChecker @ SUP.js:32paramChecker @ SUP.js:6onclick @ index.html:157
SUP.js:32 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://10.44.175.4:3680/ADMIN_BH_APP/SupWsExtService'.supChecker @      SUP.js:32paramChecker @ SUP.js:6onclick @ index.html:157
```

Что надо делать

Comment: А домен, на который уходит запрос - принадлежит вам?

Answer (score 2):

Если сторонний сайт принадлежит Вам, то в ответ необходимо включить CORS - заголовки. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

В противном случае, посылайте запросы с серверной части Вашего сайта/приложения.